# Procedural texture is stretching thin

Tags: texturing, shaders, texture-coordinates

I'm really struggling to make this for someone before Christmas and as much as I'd love to learn it all before then, I'm struggling ridiculously hard with getting textures down. I found a procedural texture and plugged it in but it's stretched out on one object, while being just fine on the other and the only way I can find to fix that involves texture coordinates, doesn't seem doable when they need group input in place.

[image: Texture Stretching]

[image: Node Map]

Comment: It's using object space, and happening on only one object, so there's a chance it's as simple as Ctrl-A > Applying the scale of that object?

Comment: If ctrl+a doesn't work, try switching Texture Coordinate to UV and editing the UVs of your objects. It's not too hard, and quick to learn for what you're needing. [Blender UV getting started](https://easyblend.org/html/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/unwrapping.html)

Comment: Have tried Control+A to change the skin's size but it didn't seem to do anything, no matter whether I entered the dimensions or not. As for the texture Coordinates, it isn't actually connected yet to the nodes, I just had it out because I was fiddling with it, my bad. @PJMDesign  I've actually figured out how to unwrap UV maps and everything but couldn't get a texture I liked figured out for it that way. I'll keep looking in the meantime

Comment: Is the texture you downloaded *actually* using object space? The mapping node in the picture isn't connected to anything. Could you upload your .blend file?

Comment: Sure thing, here's the blend file and I'm not entirely sure if it's connected or not. [Blend FIle](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4Nl3OoJB/)
And if it helps, [Here's the video the Shader/Texture came from](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8glDFmzcsGI&t=109s)